# iPhone how to clip half of the ellipse

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, draw, ellipse, clip

I have drawn ellipse:

```
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 128));
```

But i only need a half of ellipse, is there a way to clip the other half?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before calling the drawing method you can clip the context to a portion of the ellipse:

```
CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
BOOL onlyDrawTopHalf = YES;
CGFloat halfMultiplier = onlyDrawTopHalf ? -1.0 : 1.0;
CGRect ellipse = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 128);
CGRect clipRect = CGRectOffset(ellipse, 0, halfMultiplier * ellipse.size.height / 2);
CGContextClipToRect(contextRef, clipRect);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, ellipse);
// restore the context: removes the clipping
CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);
```

Comment: That solves half of my problem. Now on the other side, i want also to have half ellipse (different from the first one), but using your code again doesnt help, that new ellipse is never shown. I just change bool to NO, and some parameters of ellipse.

Comment: I have updated the code. It now restores the state of the context after drawing. Did this help?

Comment: This is what i really needed, thanks man. Do you have any idea how to clip area that looks like crescent moon? Two ellipses, one smaller, and one bigger, and to cut smaller one from the bigger one? This really could be asking too much...

Comment: You can use any path to clip the context. Simply create a current path for the context then call `CGContextClip`. Have a look at the documentation about clipping paths: CGContextClip [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip)